# problem to delete page

Tags: posts, pages

I have a "page" or "post" that I can not find anywhere. I would like to delete it, but I can not find it anywhere. I have already looked at the list of posts and pages, and even the database.

Follow the link on the page ...

[enter link description here](http://capptan.com.br/blog/como-engajar-e-reter-usuarios-de-aplicativos-em-5-estrategias-definitivas/engajar-e-reter-usuarios-de-aplicativos/)

Comment: Have you turned on your admin toolbar so that when you view the page, it shows "Edit (post type)" right there in the admin bar? That's one quick way to be able to delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is attachment, you can find it in the **Dashboard > Media** menu. 
which id is: 497, you can find it and delete it. As I can see in Inspect element this is image: http://capptan.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/engajar-e-reter-usu%C3%A1rios-de-aplicativos.jpg

But in your template, I can see you have hidden these things via CSS.

Hope you know how to delete it from Media.

Comment: The problem was that there was an image with an error in uploading and so it generated that link. Solved, thank you very much.

Comment: Great, glad to know that!